# AtTask API - creating user's time-off

Tags: api, attask

Does anyone know if it is possible to create user's time-off( personal time) using the API? We are trying to import vacation dates of users form our time management system. I checked the [documentation](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/) from top to bottom couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in the process of doing the same thing and after many frustrating hours of reading through the api and what documentation there is, I was able to find that "Reserved Time" [resvt] object is the URI where one would need to post information concerning vacation / time off days.  Originally, I was looking to update the hasNonWorkDays object, but this only returns a boolean value associated with the top-level Schedule/Sched object.

Just to clarify, I am making API calls to our scheduling system that returns JSON data and then matching the user information with AtTask userID so that I can regularly update AtTask as such.  The URL path is:
[DOMAIN].attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/resvt/search?fields=userID,startDate,endDate,customerID,name,user,task,customer

This will return RESVT ids as well as fields matching those in the URL including user's unique IDs and full name.  You will need to follow login instructions by making a POST request with USERNAME and PASSWORD found here: https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#POST .  This will return a session ID and save it in a cookie which will then allow you to search the API via the browser or something like the POSTMAN chrome extension.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I also just got the same answer from AtTask support.